# Display passwords from pass (the standard unix password manager) in dmenu-mac, by executing a shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, passwords, xdotool, dmenu

I'd like to have all the passwords, that are stored in gnu-pass (the standard unix password manager), to be displayed in dmenu-mac via a shell script.

The shell script is working, only for the `Directory/file` example.

Examples:

1. `Social/example@email.com` (one directory) *Works fine*
2. `example@email.com` (without directory) *Does not work*
3. `Social/Personal/example@email.com` (more than one directory) *Does not work*

The following modified script that satisfies the first example, is taken from https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/contrib/dmenu/passmenu

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

typeit=0
if [[ $1 == "--type" ]]; then
    typeit=1
    shift
fi

if [[ -n $DISPLAY ]]; then
    dmenu=/opt/homebrew/bin/dmenu-mac
    xdotool="xdotool type --clearmodifiers --file -"
else
    echo "Error: No Wayland or X11 display detected" >&2
    exit 1
fi

prefix=${PASSWORD_STORE_DIR-~/.password-store}
password_files=( "$prefix"/**/*.gpg )
password_files=( "${password_files[@]#"$prefix"/}" )
password_files=( "${password_files[@]%.gpg}" )

password=$(printf '%s\n' "${password_files[@]}" | "$dmenu" "$@")

[[ -n $password ]] || exit

if [[ $typeit -eq 0 ]]; then
    pass show -c "$password" 2>/dev/null
else
    pass show "$password" | { IFS= read -r pass; printf %s "$pass"; } | $xdotool
fi
```

Do modify the above script to satisfy all three examples.

My system:
Apple M1 Pro
Ventura 13.0.1

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the rewrite `gopass` instead of `pass`.

My problem with the script is that I only got 22 passwords displayed.

I could solve it by replacing `bash` by `zsh` in the first line. Where exactly this bug is I have not traced.